# how to replace 'table a'.'column b' with 'table b'.'column b' if 'table a'.'column a' matches 'table b'.'column a'

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 tables as below:-

**TABLE A**

```
-------------------------------
| product_id | price           |
-------------------------------
| 1          | 2.2000          |
| 2          | 0.0000          |
| 3          | 0.3333          |
```

**TABLE B**

```
-------------------------------
| product_id | price_discount  |
-------------------------------
| 1          | 1.8000          |
```

How can I using select statement to select out the price range for 2 tables as mentioned above?

Example:- `SELECT * FROM TABLE A WHERE **price or price discount** BETWEEN 0 AND 2;`

Expected result will show due to product_id have discount_price = 1.8 (within 0 to 2 price range).

```
 -------------------------------
 | product_id | price           |
 -------------------------------
 | 1          | 2.2000          |
 | 2          | 0.0000          |
 | 3          | 0.3333          |
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` may suffice between the two tables. `LEFT JOIN` is done because we can have non-matching rows between the two tables.

**Edit:** Previous version did extra checking of `tb.price_discount IS NOT NULL`; but it is really not needed, and `BETWEEN..AND` is enough.

It is explained in the [`OR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) operator documentation, that `1 OR NULL = 1`

```
SELECT ta.*
FROM tablea AS ta
LEFT JOIN tableb AS tb 
  ON ta.product_id = tb.product_id 
WHERE ta.price BETWEEN 0 AND 2
        OR 
      tb.price_discount BETWEEN 0 AND 2
```

Above solution is based on the assumption that there will be 0 or 1 rows corresponding to a `product_id` in the `tableb`. If there can be more, then a `GROUP BY` may be needed.

Comment: @henry check the updated version please. I optimized it further.